# Android: Cancel a countdown timer on back button

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

How do i stop a countdown timer when the devices back button is pressed (not a button I made but a back button on the device). This is what I have tried...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    flight_engineer.this.finish();
        win.cancel();
        win = null;
        Log.i("backPressed","hello");



}
```

This log does print the hello but the timer (which is called win) still counts when i am the new activity.

EDIT: This is how I use the Timer

```
   win = new CountDownTimer(120000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

           if(alti >= 28000 && alti <= 33000 && speed >= 280 && speed <= 320 && pressure >= 8 && pressure <= 12
                   && over_heat >= 700 && over_heat <= 750 && fuel > 50){

               Intent start = new Intent(flight_engineer.this, win.class);
               finish();
               flight_engineer.this.startActivity(start);

           }
            else
           {
               Intent start = new Intent(flight_engineer.this, losing.class);
               finish();
               flight_engineer.this.startActivity(start);

           }



        }
    };
    win.start();
```

this is where i declare out the top of my code:

```
public class flight_engineer extends AppCompatActivity {

int fuel = 100;
int alti = 10000;
int speed = 100;
int over_heat = 600;
int pressure = 10;
boolean started = true;

CountDownTimer fuelCount;
CountDownTimer PSICount;
CountDownTimer speedTimer;
CountDownTimer spike;
CountDownTimer win;
```

Comment: Where is the timer started?

Comment: Is this your Activity?
flight_engineer.this.finish();

Call finish() after you call

win.cancel();
win = null;
Log.i("backPressed","hello");

Or post your whole code.

Comment: I have updated code